# django AuthenticationForm how to remove error messages

Tags: django

I created a custom error message for auth form, however, I'm not sure how to remove the error message from django AuthenticationForm? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

form:

```
class CustomAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserCreationForm
        fields = ['username','password']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomAuthForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'placeholder': 'email'})
        self.fields['username'].label = False
        self.fields['password'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs={ 'placeholder':'password'}) 
        self.fields['password'].label = False
```

HTML:"

```
    <form method = 'POST' class="container-fluid" style ="position: relative;">
    {{ login_form }}
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <button type = 'submit' value ='sign_in' name = 'submit' class = 'default-bg'>Log In</button>
    <div class = "email_ph">@</div>
    </form>
```

[image]

Comment: can you share the HTML template that renders this page

Answer (score 1):

check this official documentation :

[Django Auth forms official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/)

[ 5th class from top ]

**You can override the Error Messages that you display.**

[image: Error Message in Auth forms Django]

Comment: I fixed the problem with css, display none on errorlist.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get rid of all error messages that display, this is the least complicated way to do it.  Just add this code to the body of the login.html page:

```
<style>
.errorlist {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```